# AC_error_rate objective function in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a loss function, but I keep having trouble

It check for the number of y_pred == y_true. It must be a exact match

I tried something like

```
def AC_ERROR_RATE(y_true,y_pred):
    AC = 0
    for a,b in (y_true,y_pred):
        if a == b then AC++
    return AC
```

But since you can't iterate through tensor it obviously didn't work
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write this using tf.map_fn and tf.cond instead of for and if, and reducing the result.